# Sending lots of email from web server

Tags: wordpress, email, sendmail, spam

I have site where people can send posts (Wordpress based website). Each post have a form which anyone can use to send email to the author of the post. I think at some point there might be heavy traffic on site and that could mean hundreds and hopefully thousands emails leaving from different posts pages per day. What should i take account that the emails don't get attached to spam filters? Or should I use some 3rd party system for this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I usually do by default is add a TEXT record to my DNS (SPF Record) indicating that this server is an authorized sender for my domain.

If the server is on the same network as your mail server, you can relay the mail through your mail server.

If the mail server is not on the same network, you could sent the mail through SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Make a reputation system of your site users ( like stackoverflow for example) and give mail power just to those that managed to get a number of points ( or whatever you will use for reputation). This way, at least, you won't get abused by spammers. Moreover, if someone abuse his power, you can "ban" him from sending emails.

About spam filters, if you have a dedidated server, could use your local smtp with some antispam solution instaled, to drop those messages that are spammy, to stop them at the source.

Also, use SPF and DKIM but those won't ensure that your mails won;t end up in trash, just protects your identify as mail sender, and others can't impersonate you.